# Where is the Capitol Corridor bus stop for the Moscone Center located?

Tags: buses, san-francisco, amtrak

The Amtrak map online says it is at 747 Howard St in San Francisco, but I am looking around and I don't see any bus stop indicators.

Answer (score 4):

The map online is incorrect; the station stop is actually located at 794 Howard Street, near Jillian's and the Target Guest Pickup sign. There is an "Amtrak Bus Stop" sign on a light pole about 1foot wide by 2ft tall.

[image: Bus stop location]

Comment: Could you please add a link to Google maps?

Comment: You can see the Amtrak Bus Stop sign [on Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.783551,-122.402382,3a,45y,278.32h,85.25t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sh0smpRYtFsJYGhZ68eV_yA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656). At this writing, GSV is showing a white delivery truck in the spot where the bus would stop.